# Regex that matches anything between ' '

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x

Please can you help me about this:

consider the following line:

```
"Duplicate entry 'blah@gmail.com' for key 'email'"
```

I need a regex that matches any thing between ' ' incloding white spaces, new lines, and also any ' character between ' '

the code im using is: (Python)

```
value = "Duplicate entry 'blah@gmail.com' for key 'email'"
dict = re.findall(r'regex goes here', value)
print dict[0]
print dict[1]
```

i need to print:

```
blah@gmail.com

email
```

Comment: How is it supposed to tell one "'" from the next?

Comment: I don't know,, it seems that its Impossible :(

Comment: Why don't you give a *real* example of a message and we'll tell you how you *should* be parsing it.

Comment: what about ignoring " ' " between " ' ' " ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> m = re.match("Duplicate entry '(?P<value>.*)' for key '(?P<key>.*)'", "Duplicate entry 'blah@gmail.com' for key 'email'")
>>> m.group('value')
'blah@gmail.com'
>>> m.group('key')
'email'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string = "Duplicate entry 'blah@gmail.com' for key 'email'"
pattern = re.compile("'[^']*'")
matches = pattern.findall(string)
# matches == ["'blah@gmail.com'", "'email'"]
```

If you want to force the quotes to have at least one character in them:

```
pattern = re.compile("'[^']+')
```